# Can't import scala.actors.Actor._ in intellij scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, actor

I recently installed intellij IDEA for scala programming
right now I do a tutorial on scala.actors and now Im experiencing a strange error when I try to `import scala.actors.Actor._` the error-message is

> cannot resolve symbol actors

I dont have problems like that in eclipse so I think I have installed the scala plugin wrong somehow..

maybe anything is missing in here?:

> External Libraries
>
> - <1.8> (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle)
> - scala-sdk-2.11.6

Thanks for any help in advance!
Oh and this is my first question on Stackoverflow, so if I did anything wrong don't hesitate to correct me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Scala `2.10` Scala Actors are moved to an external package (and **deprecated** in favour of [Akka](http://akka.io)).

Check this out: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html

If you really need them, try adding `scala-actors` as a [dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.scala-lang%7Cscala-actors%7C2.11.7%7Cjar).

Answer (score 0):

Scala actors are deprecated in scala 2.11: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html

The recommendation is to use Akka instead. The tutorial you are following is probably out of date, try an akka tutorial instead.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer! 
im checking out sbt right now, so is guess ill be alright

Answer (score 0):

When I use REPL it able to import the actor where as Intellij is not able resolve. 
I agree that Actors are depreciated, But I am curious to know about REPL. How It could identify Actor.

Refer the below log,

```
>scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor
```